# How long can pH solution calibration be used for?

Tags: ph

I am using a pH meter regularly (6 to 12 time per week), used mostly for home-food processing (mostly measuring the acidity of whey).

The meter requires weekly calibration, which is quite time consuming.

I usually prepare the solutions and then discard them. However, I was wondering: how long can I actually keep the solutions for? What is their shelf-life? Do I need to prepare the solutions weekly or can I keep them longer?

Comment: If you are using ultrapure water and storing the solutions bottled in a dark cool place they should keep for months, I would think. One brand of unopened commercial buffer has an official shelf life of 2 years. Commercial solutions have been filtered to reduce microbial growth. Various websites suggest not keeping opened solutions longer than 6 months but hesitate to provide an exact time since this depends on the conditions in which they are kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deviate from the given procedures, you are on your own and you have to experiment and verify.

One way is, after the calibration, to save calibration solution(s) to be used as the control sample. You then periodically measure its pH whenever you measure true samples.

If the pH of this control sample deviates from its nominal value more than is acceptable for you, prepare new solutions and recalibrate. Note the needed time interval for this recalibration and then eventually decide to use this (or shorter) interval as your regular recalibration routine.

Note that it is not only about the pH drift of calibration solutions, but also about pH drift of the device itself (pH electrode). The mentioned measuring of control samples addresses both.

Comment: So you're saying it is not advisable to do it but not impossible and I should compare a fresh calibration solution against a preserved one over time and compare the delta?

Comment: Rather, doing so, it is expected you know what you are doing. I do not say comparing fresh vs preserved calibration. I mean continuing normal pH measurement and evaluating measured pH of preserved solution with its expected pH  value. E.g if the calibration solution has nominal pH 4.00 and if you meaure its pH after 4 weeks as 4.2, you know something is off and you need to recalibrate with fresh solutions.( at least 2)

Comment: Note that serious measurements in labs involve recallibrations before every measurement or every day, depending on measurement frequency.

Answer (score -1):

pH 7 and 4 buffers are very stable if air contact is minimized. A fresh buffer should be used for every calibration. My procedure was to store the electrodes in pH4 buffer. Each morning measure the millivolt reading of the solution, rinse, replace with the previous pH7 buffer record the mv reading, calibrate with fresh pH7 buffer recording the mv reading in the log book. set the slope at pH4 with fresh buffer after recording the mv value. The difference should be the Nernst equation value ~175mv; the mv readings should be almost constant. I have found that electrodes slowly drift and eventually fail[unless broken first]. If a new bottle of buffer is used check the mv readings with the old and new they should agree. This takes less time to do than to read. After a while any problems with electrodes, meters or buffer solutions will be immediately apparent. I recommend Fisher Scientific color coded buffers.